# Using react-native-modalbox in ListView causes modalbox to only fill the list item space instead of full screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

When I use the package react-native-modalbox with a FlatList (each list item can spawn a distinct modal when tapped), the modal that is spawned only fills the area of the list item instead of going full screen like it normally should.

A working snack that shows the issue is here:

https://snack.expo.io/BkICbjwWQ

For completeness I'll paste the code in here as well:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import Modal from "react-native-modalbox";

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'; // Version can be specified in package.json

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let myRefs = [];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <View>
                      <Modal
                        style={[styles.modal]}
                        ref={(modalItem) => {myRefs[item.key] = modalItem;} }
                        swipeToClose={true}
                        onClosed={this.onClose}
                        onOpened={this.onOpen}
                        onClosingState={this.onClosingState}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Basic modal</Text>
                    </Modal><Text>{item.key}</Text><Button title="Basic Modal" onPress={() => myRefs[item.key].open()} style={styles.btn}>Basic modal</Button></View>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

I basically have the same question/problem as ([react-native-modalbox stuck in child component context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581021/react-native-modalbox-stuck-in-child-component-context#43588664)) but there was no answer to that question and he did not provide enough details with a minimum working example.

Comment: try using coverScreen={true} as a prop to your modal. it may help you

Comment: Wow! You're a genius! and I need to read the documentation more closely...

Comment: i think you render modal view in listview item is not good pattern. You should pass  callback on item press to root view then process open modal there.

Answer (score 1):

Your modal component is inside the rendered item. This causes it to be bound to the item. Although you can fix this issue by using appropriate props or some custom styling, this is not efficient. You would have 1000 modal components if you had 1000 items in your list.

You should move out your modal component and make it sibling to the `FlatList`. This way you would have only single modal. You can change the contents of the modal with a state value.

**Sample**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let myRefs = [];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          style={[styles.modal]}
          ref={modalItem => { myRefs['modal'] = modalItem; }}
          swipeToClose={true}
          onClosed={this.onClose}
          onOpened={this.onOpen}
          onClosingState={this.onClosingState}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Basic modal</Text>
        </Modal>
        <FlatList
          data={[{ key: 'a' }, { key: 'b' }]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.key}</Text>
              <Button
                title="Basic Modal"
                onPress={() => myRefs['modal'].open()}
                style={styles.btn}>
                Basic modal
              </Button>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```